# Loop including FPS

Tags: java

How can I improve this main game loop that monitors and displays frames per second?

```
    public void run() {
    running=true;
    initengine();
    initgame();
    //Initialise game loop
    long looptime, difference=0,timetaken=0;
    int frames=0;
    fps=0;
    //Main game Loop
    while(running){
        while (timetaken < 1000 ){   
        looptime=System.currentTimeMillis();

           update();
           render();

           try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

            frames++;
            timetaken+=difference;
            difference=(System.currentTimeMillis()-looptime); 
        }
        fps=frames;
        frames=0;
        timetaken=0;
    }        
System.exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Thread.sleep(...)` in the middle of your game loop is a problem. No-one wants to see that.

A really simple solution to this problem is do things a little differently....

```
long nextSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
int frames = 0;
while (running) {

    ....
    // Do your game loop work...
    ....

    frames++;
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now > nextSecond) {
        fps = frames;
        frames = 0;
        nextSecond = now + 1000;
    }
}
```

This removes the sleep, and the nested loop.